# Evaluate $\iint_Rxy^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dxdy$, where $R={(xy)\in{\Bbb{R}^2}:1\le{x^2}+y^2\le{4},y\ge{0}}.$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have no idea where to start with this one? And how to step through it.

How would I set the limits for this? And then what would I go on to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you studied polar coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Polar coordinate $$ x=r \cos \theta$$ $$ y=r \sin \theta$$ then $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r $$ and your dommain rewrites $$ 1\leq r\leq 2, \quad 0\leq \theta \leq \pi$$ and $$ dx\:dy=r\:dr\:d\theta$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: No idea what to do from there. Wild guess that I substitute r back in so it will be $\int_1^2\int_0^{\pi}\sqrt{rcos^2\theta+rsin^2\theta}drd\theta$ or am I wayyy off (I imagine I am... Sorry.)

Answer (score 2):

if you switch to polar coordinates the integral becomes:
$$
\int_{r=1}^{r=2} \int_0^{\pi} r^5 \cos \theta \sin^2 \theta d\theta dr
$$

Answer (score 2):

Replacing x with -x does not change R and reverses the sign of the Integrand.
Answer: 0